# Discrete Math Values for a vertex!

Tags: graph-theory

In a graph with eight vertices, seven of the vertices have valences $1,3,3,4,5,6,7$. Which values are possible for the eighth vertex’s valence?

I know the handshaking lemma but how can I think about it? I start to think like this $\sum \deg(v) = 2\cdot|E|$, but then I get stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: You can simply start trying to construct the graph. It has a vertex of degree $7$; that vertex must be connected to all of the other vertices. It has a vertex of degree $6$ that must be connected to all but one of the other vertices. The one to which the vertex of degree $6$ is *not* connected must be the vertex of degree $1$. If you draw that much, you have a vertex of degree $7$, a vertex of degree $6$, five vertices of degree $2$, and a vertex of degree $1$. One of the vertices of degree $2$ must have degree $5$ in the completed graph; it’s already connected to the vertices of degree $6$ and $7$, and it can’t be connected to the vertex of degree $1$, so it must be connected to $3$ of the other vertices of degree $2$. When you draw that much you have the following graph:

[image: partial graph]

The red numbers show the degrees of the completed vertices. The other four vertices are labelled $u,v,w$, and $x$. Currently $u,v$, and $x$ have degree $3$, and $w$ has degree $2$. One of these four vertices must end up with degree $4$.

- Explain why $w$ cannot be the vertex of degree $4$ in the final graph.

The vertices $u,v$, and $x$ all have the same neighbors, so it doesn’t matter which one of them we choose to be the vertex of degree $4$ in the final graph. Say that we choose $u$. Then we must add an edge from $u$ to $v,w$, or $x$.

- Why can we not add an edge from $u$ to $v$ or $x$?
- After we add an edge from $u$ to $w$, do we have a graph whose vertices have the right degrees? Can we add any more edges and still have vertices with the right degrees?

Comment: What do you mean by the right degrees??

Comment: @Jonas: Degrees compatible with the requirements of the problem: there must be at least one vertex of degree $7$, at least one with degree $6$, at least one with degree $5$, at least one with degree $4$, at least two with degree $3$, and at least one with degree $1$.